# Could not load file or assembly System.DirectoryServices. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, directoryservices

Getting started with a new project. But this exception is bugging me when I try to run an .aspx page. This project has a reference to System.DirectoryServices dll. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome!  What .NET version are you using?  What is the properties for the reference to System.DirectoryServices dll?

Comment: Check if your `Project -> Properties -> Application -> Target framework` matches the `System.DirectoryServices dll` version.

Comment: @Micky: I'm using .Net Framework 4.5 and System.DirectoryServices is getting picked up from GAC of version 1.0.3300.0 and my project target version is .net framework 3.5

Comment: @Jeroen: Project .Net version is 3.5 and dll version says 1.0.3300.0

Comment: Thats a dll versioninfo, not the .Net version.